# hook_menu_alter for taxonomy vocabulary

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, routes

My vocabularies machine name is `vocab_ . $account_id` .
First Funcs: too see the user $account_id is the same with vocab.. if yes then return TRUE.

```
function _term_account(){
  global $base_url;
  global $user;
  $account_id = custom_get_user_account_id();
  $tesr = explode('_', arg(3));
// admin/structure/taxonomy/vocab_21117 .. witch 21117 is $account_id
 if($tesr[1] == $account_id){
    return true;
 } else {
    return false;
 }
}
```

I use `hook_menu_alter` to alter the taxonomy url:

```
function custom_menu_alter(&$items) {
  // Works fine.. So every user has he's own and only vocabulary..
  $items['admin/structure/taxonomy/%taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name/list']['access callback'] = '_term_account';
  // DOESN'T WORK.
  $items['admin/structure/taxonomy/%taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name/add']['access callback'] = '_term_account';
}
```

**UPDATE**
When User edit term..

```
function _term_account_edit(){
    $account_id = custom_get_user_account_id();
    global $base_url;
    $term = taxonomy_term_load(arg(2));
    if($term->vocabulary_machine_name == 'branches_'.$account_id){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

function custom_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['taxonomy/term/%taxonomy_term/edit']['access callback'] = '_term_account_edit'; 
}
```

The `Delete` Button dosen't Show up? Why?

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work? Presumably you're expecting access to be granted/denied and _that's_ not working, but how have you identified that line as the culprit, as opposed to, say, another module with a higher weight also implementing hook_menu_alter for that path? We need more to go on than just that one function, some context and the results of your own debugging are needed too

Comment: Adding to @Clive, we do now know the expected behavior. What is your intention? From the url you want to block people from adding terms to a certain vocabulary right? This does not restrict access to creating vocabularies.

Comment: @Neograph734 i need only certien users to add term to certien vocab

Comment: Please edit the question and include some more details :)

Comment: @Neograph734 update it

Comment: Is it possible that there is an issue with the function name being underscored?

Comment: @Kevin actually when i try to name function without underscored the form `return false`..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix it ..
Just disable **taxonomy_access_fix** module cause it has the same menu alter with access callback ..

Comment: There is no way anyone would know this - that is not a core module nor mentioned in your original question.

Comment: @Kevin in first place i don't know is Any module use menu alter exactly like i use it above.. so that's why i search for `$items['admin/structure/taxonomy/%taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name/add']['access callback']` in the whole modules .. then i found out taxonomy_access_fix module use the same menu alter..

Answer (score 1):

The code looks good! However, try the following:

- See if there is already a permission or a module which lets you control the things you wish to control. Maybe you can mention the desired outcome or the objective in the question?
- Add a `dpm()` or something to the end of the function to see if the `$items` are being modified correctly.
- Add a `dpm()` or something in the `_term_account()` function to see if it is being called correctly and that it is returning `TRUE` or `FALSE` correctly as per your requirements.

Comment: it works fine with "list".. but when i try to "add" any term .. return false..

Comment: What's different between `['access callback'] = '_term_account';` and `['access callback'] = _term_account();` the weird thing it all works fine :)

Comment: Well, access callback is supposed to be a `callable`, i.e. a function or a method. If it is a callable, then Drupal will call it with `access arguments`, if any, and the output of the callback will decide if the user can access the path. However, `_term_account()` will not be a valid `callable`, so it might be evaluated as a boolean `TRUE` and then all users might have access to the path without any access check. I think setting `_term_account()` might even throw errors, if not, then the boolean `TRUE` thing is happening, which is a security issue.

Comment: So what about `Delete` button? Is something wrong in my code that avoid show the delete btn ?

Comment: Try debugging your access callback and check if you are returning `TRUE` or `FALSE` correctly for the delete case. Your access callback doesn't need to load the taxonomy term like you are doing. Use 2 arguments in your access callback, `$term, $action` and then use `access arguments = [2, 'edit']`, etc as the case maybe. Try to study an existing access callback provided by some other module. I think you are not properly returning `TRUE` for delete access. See https://www.drupal.org/node/553368.